# Minor typo in the Metaverse blog post

Tags: bug, blog, spelling

In [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/23/youre-living-in-the-metaverse-you-just-dont-know-it-yet/):

- The leading "t" is not included in the link for "trading virtual sword and shields in World of Warcraft".
- The phrase probably should read "...sword**s**..." ([by Ryan M](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8988006#8988006))

Comment: Obligatory comment about someone deprecated bludgeoning someone to deprecated with a giant deprecated

Comment: Or the more modern "Very small self adhesive 's'es will be provided for a nominal Shipping and Handling Charge"

Comment: nah, does not sound as good. Modern sensitivities suck all the fun out of this world :( A couple more nitpicks to keep this on-topic: "real-world", "face-to-face" (what's with the fear of dashes?), and "fully" (you can't get "more fully").

Answer (score 5):

More nitpicks/typos in addition to the one quoted from me above:

- "it’s increasing presence in our lives" should be "its"
- "two fold" is [one word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twofold)
- the "tweet from [Epic Games in 2019](https://twitter.com/TimSweeneyEpic/status/1157841800385695744)" probably should be something like "tweet from Epic Games Founder/CEO Tim Sweeney" since it's not from the company itself (though the company has been [pretty explicit about its Metaverse goals](https://www.epicgames.com/site/en-US/news/announcing-a-1-billion-funding-round-to-support-epics-long-term-vision-for-the-metaverse)).